# Redirect apache commons logging to Eclipse's logging mechanism?

Tags: eclipse, logging, eclipse-plugin, httpclient, apache-commons

I'm trying to use the `org.apache.commons.httpclient` plugin in a Eclipse RCP application I'm writing.

For some reason the logging from the httpclient plugin is going to stderr (via apache commons logging, I think).

Does anyone know if there is a way to redirect the logging from the httpclient plugin to the standard Eclipse logging mechanism?

Thanks!